Is the Motorola 68HC705C8P readable? How?
I have to extract the original program (.hex) from a 40 pin 68HC705C8P. I tried to look over some of the methods that involved around using Universal Programmer.  So far, I took the chip to run some readings on Hi-Lo all 100 at one of the avaliable elec-stores, but they said that it couldn't be read. They said that the MCU is unreadable and it might need the other adapter to read it, so I am not entirely sure what to do. Then, I found iProg V86 on the internet the other days and the price is somewhat affordable, so I looked into their software. To no avail, the  closest part number is 68HC705B32 which is different part number. In a nutshell, I need a way to read and clone the program inside an MC68HC705C8P.  I am not entirely sure if it has been locked from manufacturer or not.

Is the heading question alright now?

I can't quickly find datasheets to see if they are actually related, but I did see this one recently, relating to the MC1468705G2 http://worldphaco.com/uploads/The%20MC1468705G2%20%20MCU%20ROM%20Data%20Extraction%20Project.pdf I

According to the manual (page 184/185) there is a PROM security bit. If this bit is set the PROM can't be read.

What's data retention like on these parts? It's so old that I'd expect the memory to start failing.

@nanash1 Given enough money, you will likely find a reverse engineering lab that that can extract the firmware for you, possibly with destructive probing methods. These security bits are just for preventing casual copying.

@Lundin I was told that it was able to operate normally.

@Justme Yeah iirc Motorola didn't have much in the way of security in the predecessor 68HC08 either, but didn't get that proper until the predecessor's predecessor S08.

I think you need an universal programmers that explicitly list the MC68HC705C8P as supported.

The following method won't work if the SEC bit was set during programming, see manual page 184/185.
I don't know if there are any modern programmer that support this MCU, but you can build your own. The circuit is explained in chapter 9 of the MC68HC705C8A technical data manual.
A simpler programming circuit is also described on the now offline www.midondesign.com website, which is still available via archive.org.

(source: midondesign.com)
As you can see, it's mainly a serial interface. The website also provides a simple DOS program named "PROG7.COM" which is still accessible via archive.org. This program can be used to dump the PROM if security isn't enabled. The program obviously won't work on a modern PC, but runs on emulation frameworks like DOSbox.
